# grep fails to find text in docx file

Tags: command-line, grep, search

I cannot find the reason why grep cannot find the file with the word 'coomunities'. I used

```
grep -ril --include=GLOB "coomunities"  .
```

Note: communities is on purpose mispelled.
The file is a docx and currently has permissions '-rwxrwxrwx'. I tried

- run from the same folder or other folder
- changed permission to file
- tried a different words for the same file (Ubuntu, linux, literacy)
- include specifically docx extension
- I tried the GUI of searchmonkey which can find the file correctly
  still the file seems not appearing in any search using grep. Any idea?

Comment: hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40564217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues.

1. You Can't grep a docx file. Grep works with standard output files or text. Docx is encoded
   Take a look at this
   [How to search multiple DOCX files for a string within a Word field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296122/how-to-search-multiple-docx-files-for-a-string-within-a-word-field)
   A quick way to verify this is to `cat <file>.docx` and see if what come out is readable or not.
2. Outside of the docx issue. I haven't used GLOB in grep, but my understanding is that it is pretty limited. Your better off using regex. Something like this

   `grep -Ei "coom[^[:space:]]+" *.<File Ext>`
3. Personally when I can't find something I know should be there, I change the needle, not the haystack. Try "coom" or even "coo".
4. I don't think permission are the issue. Run the `cat` command, if you can read it then you don't need to change permission for grep.

Hope that helps.